# How do I pass errors='coerce' to pd.to_datetime from pd.read_excel in Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

I'm having an issue converting some date fields when using `pd.read_excel`

```
cols_A8_J2007[i] = pd.read_excel(i, ('sheet'+str(j)), headers = 1, skiprows = 6, nrows=2000, usecols = 'A:J', converters = {'Expired': pd.to_datetime, 'Valid Until': pd.to_datetime})
```

I'd like to be able to pass `errors='coerce'` when the function is called, but I'm not sure how to do that as I only pass the function; so there must be some other argument to read_excel I have to pass in order to pass that when `pd.to_datetime` is called.

[Pandas error trying to convert string into integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608282/pandas-error-trying-to-convert-string-into-integer)

Comment: You can use a lambda: `'Valid Until': lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce')` or [`functools.partial`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331726/how-does-functools-partial-do-what-it-does/44814021)

Comment: I would just do: `cols_A8_J2007[i]['Expired'] = pd.to_datetime(cols_A8..., errors='coerce')` after reading the dataframe with `read_excel`.